# Loading an image URL into a Kotlin AppWidget using Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I scoured the internet looking for a sample of how to load a remote image in Kotlin. There are plenty of Kotlin examples using Glide with a normal ImageView, but there is nothing related to remote ImageViews within an AppWidget.

The best resource at the moment is here, but it is in Java:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-innnto-notifications-and-appwidgets

I've added a Kotlin translation below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DeviceIntelWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, 
    appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        ...
        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget)
        val awt: AppWidgetTarget = object : AppWidgetTarget(context.applicationContext, R.id.img, remoteViews, *appWidgetIds) {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
            }
        };    
        Glide.with(context.applicationContext).asBitmap().load("https://si.com/img.jpg").into(awt)
        ...
    }
}
```

Notes:

- AppWidgetTarget is used to display downloaded Bitmaps inside an ImageView of an AppWidget through RemoteViews
- Call load to load the bitmaps and do any post processing inside onResourceReady
- implementation `'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'` force closes with `NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap`
- Updating to the latest: 4.7.1 fixes the problem